# What does `decay_copy` in the constructor in a `std::thread` object do?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, templates, types

I am trying to understand the constructor of a `std::thread` but fail to understand how parameter types are represented/handled. Judging from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), a simplified constructor could be  sketched as follows:

```cpp
class thread {
   public:
    template <class Function, class Arg>
    thread(Function&& f, Arg&& arg) {
        // something happening
        std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)),
                    decay_copy(std::forward<Arg>(arg)));
        // something else happening
    }
};
```

cppreference defines `decay_copy` as:

```cpp
template <class T>
std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }
```

I experimented a bit with the following examples:

```cpp
struct X{};
int main() {
    X x1{};
    X& x2 = x1;
    auto f = []() { return; };
    thread t1{f, x1}; // arg should be of type X& after the inner std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    thread t2{f, x2}; // arg should be of type X& after the inner std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    thread t3{f, X{}}; // arg should be of type X&& after the inner std::forward<Arg>(arg);
}
```

According to my analysis, both `x1` and `x2` are of type lvalue reference after the inner `std::forward` while`X{}` is of type rvalue reference. I believe we somehow need to separate `x1` and `x2`  to pass it by value or by reference. The analysis leads me to three questions:

- Is the analysis above correct?
- How does `decay_copy` untangle the types correctly?
- After starting at this for some time, I wonder: Oh bother, why is this so involved? Could it be done easier? The answer is, of course, no, but I still lack intuition for the entire operation.

I am grateful for any hints, suggestions, or explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Std thread makes a copy (or move) into a decayed version of the arguments type.  The decayed version is not a reference nor const nor volatile nor an array (arrays and functions become pointers).

If you want an lvalue reference argument, use a reference wrapper.  The called function in the thread ctor gets an rvalue otherwise; decay copy just determines how the rvalue you are passed in the thread function is constructed from your std thread argument.